# My boolean works for a few times and then it goes nuts. Is it the Jquery .click cache?

Tags: jquery, click, boolean

I have this fiddle and I want whenever I press a button to flip the positions of two panels.
The code works very well for a couple of times and then it starts throwing false and true at the same time . Have a look at the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/alexnode/RYchY/2/

I call this function to switch the panels

```
function switchpanels() {

    if (panelswitched === false) {
        $(".centralpanel").css("left", "75%");
        $(".trpanel").css("left", "50%");
         panelswitched = true;
        return;//not sure if needed 

    } else if (panelswitched === true) {
        $(".centralpanel").css("left", "50%");
        $(".trpanel").css("left", "75%");
        panelswitched = false;
        return;
    }
```

I use the same button id to call the switchpanels but from different functions.

```
  function german() {


            switchpanels();

            $("#tr1").text("German to Urdu");

            $("#tr1").click(function () {
                urdu();
            });


    }

    function urdu() {

            switchpanels();
            $("#tr1").text("Urdu to English");
            $("#tr1").click(function () {
                english();
            });
```

Each function will have many cases but I simplified it for posting. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Is it that the click is cashed from the previous function ? Or is it something very basic ?

Comment: As a newbie stop blaming jquery - in next several months every weird behaviour will be caused by your terrible code, not jquery itself. In this case you're binding click handlers multiple times, so that's why every handler is called multiple times as well.

Comment: I didn't mean that it is Jquery's fault I just thought that whenever I add the .click handler it overwrites it with the new attributes. By the way my code is unbelievably good ... if it does what it should do .. which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the answer to my question is to use .off .on that way I am able to use the same  button to pass from function to function. Because I am quite a rookie I will not mark the answer as correct until I get some up votes. But my code works at least on the surface ...

http://jsfiddle.net/alexnode/RYchY/3/

```
$("#tr1").show().text("French to German").off('click').on('click',function(){ german("fr");});
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are attaching a new click handler whenever you call the `german` function. So if you call it 5 times the handler is called 5 times. Put it outside of the context of the `german` function and use `.trigger('click')` instead.

```
function german() {
    switchpanels();
    $("#tr1").text("German to Urdu").trigger('click'); // trigger the click event
}
// The click handler
$("#tr1").click(urdu);
```

Comment: This crashes my jsfiddle big time ! I believe I have to change the way I structured my project.

Comment: the trigger doesn't work in my case because I want to pass the function name in my click event. Ideally I would like to use the trigger but with a new function at the end. I was looking at the .on and . off but I don't understand the handler events very well. I am not sure i can explain it very well but you can see in my fiddle that i press the tr1 button and go to a function then i press the button again and go to another function i will have to do go to about 20 different function that do different things.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested but this should be much easier:

```
var languages = ['German', 'Urdu', 'English', 'Spanish'], //however many you want
    cur_language = 0;

function switchLanguage() {
    switchpanels();
    var new_language = cur_language + 1;
    if (new_language === languages.length) {
        new_language = 0;
    }
    $("#tr1").text(languages[cur_language] + " to " + languages[new_language]);
    cur_language = new_language;
}

$("#tr1").click(function () {
    switchLanguage();
});
```

Comment: That's great. But there is problem that my project which is a "chinese whispers" game of translation! Each language branches to many others and then comes back (while loosing something of the original text) for example english has 7 different versions translated from other languages. I have a diagram that I call a knot which is demoralising. I ended up doing 6 different paths with +1 and at the end i wasn't able to understand where the user was.  then I moved to the more manual way of sending each language to a function with a argument 'origin' and acting accordingly.